# How to shrink mysql database size for older projects?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.6

In my project I have used MySQL 5.6. This database contains data of last 6 years. Now the size is nearly 12GB and when my system runs, I can see it occupies around 3GB of RAM in my windows server. So I am looking for a solution/suggestion here to reduce the system load and increase the performance. 
Is it possible to reduce the database size by deleting specific old data from specific tables, will it help to increase the database performance?
it is requirement to keep at least last 2 years of data into the database.

Comment: You can offload the very old data into a separate archive database (perhaps even on a different server). If you have very long tables then decreasing their length will definitely help - but it is difficult to say how much as it depends both on your data model and the usage distribution.

Comment: Is there any tool to do it or I have to do it manually? What tools are used in the software industries to perform data archiving?

Comment: You can try PT-Archiver (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-archiver.html) from Percona Toolkit. I have not used it, though.

Comment: Does percona toolkit support windows platform?

Comment: No, the toolkit is for Linux only - but the PT-Archiver seems to be a simple Perl script so you might be able to run in under Windows if you install Perl interpreter.